# Auth Privledge FQL query faunaDB create permission denied with udr for collection

Tags: javascript, next.js, faunadb

I have the following user defined role in security with a predicate function on the create for a collection called formEntryData. Now I can create if I don't have the function which is below.

Under the Create function option

```
Lambda("values", Equals(Identity(), Select(["data"], Var("values"))))
```

Now I am creating a request with the following code, which works when the create is just set to all via checking the box, but if I use the function above it fails with permission denied. I must be doing somethign wrong

```
import { query as q } from "faunadb";
import { serverClient } from "../../utils/fauna-auth";
import { authClient } from "../../utils/fauna-auth";
import { getAuthCookie } from "../../utils/auth-cookies";

export default async (req, res) => {
  //   const { firstName, lastName, telephone, creditCardNumber } = req.body;
  const token = getAuthCookie(req);
  console.log(token);

  const data = req.body.data;
  var element = req.body.data;

  element["FormID"] = req.body.id;

  try {
    await authClient(token).query(
      q.Create(q.Collection("FormEntryData"), {
        data: element,
      })
    );
    res.status(200).end();
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: e.message });
  }
};
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE: I have also added a index for the collection and given it read permissions in the Role

Answer (score 0):

This was also asked on the Fauna community forums: https://forums.fauna.com/t/roles-membership-auth-token-permissions-denied/1681/4

It looks like two things were needed:

- update the `create` predicate to match the `data.user` field:  `Lambda("values", Equals(CurrentIdentity(), Select(["data", "user"], Var("values"))))`, and
- a user field needs to be provided in order to pass the provided predicate.

The answer in the forums used two requests: One to retrieve the calling user document (with `CurrentIdentity()`), and another to create the `FormEntryData` document.  This can be (should be) done with a single request to limit cost (Every request to Fauna will take at least one [Transactional Compute Op](https://docs.fauna.com/fauna/current/concepts/billing)), and of course network time for two round trips.  Consider the following:

```js
await authClient(token).query(
  Let(
    {
      userRef: q.CurrentIdentity(),
    },
    q.Create(q.Collection("FormEntryData"), {
      data: {
        ...element,
        user: q.Var("userRef")
      }
    })
  )
);
```